# "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Todo[]'." How to resolve this?

Tags: angular8

in my angular 8 app i have this service :

```
export class TodoService {
  private url:string ="http://192.168.99.100:2403/todos";
  sTodos:Subject<Todo[]>= new Subject<Todo[]>();
  sTodos$=this.sTodos.asObservable();

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

getTodos(){
    return this.http.get(this.url).map((r)=>{
    let data = r.json();      
    this.sTodos.next(data);  

  });
}
```

in my component i call getTodos function:

```
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {
  todos:Todo[]=[];

  constructor(private todoService:TodoService) { }

  ngOnInit(){    
  this.todoService.getTodos().subscribe((todos) =>{
    this.todos = todos;

  });
}

}
```

i get this error

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Todo[]'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422338/property-subscribe-does-not-exist-on-type-subscription-did-you-mean-unsub?noredirect=1#comment105031813_59422338 - getTodos still lacks an explicit type and your map callback still doesn't return anything.

Comment: How can i fix it?

Comment: Return the data from the map, as I keep saying. But I don't think you can be using Angular 8, because that's not valid RxJS 6+.

Comment: i follow an angular 2 training but i practice it using angular 8 that's why i am facing some problems

Comment: I'd strongly recommend finding more up-to-date materials, or this is going to be very difficult. Alternatively use the matching version of Angular, but you'll be learning things that are out of date.

Comment: yes certainly !

Comment: you can subscribe to `sTodos$` as you already declared types

Answer (score -2):

You can add an explicit type to the `http` call.

**EDIT:**

If you're using Angular 8, you should also use the new [Http Client](https://angular.io/guide/http)

```js
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

getTodos(){
    return this.http.get<Todo[]>(this.url)
        .pipe(
            tap((data)=>{
                this.sTodos.next(data);  
            });  
        )
}
```

Comment: How's that going to help? It doesn't change the return type and I don't think the old Http supported generic types.

Comment: Missed that its just `http`, but it does set the return type of `this.getTodos`

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbvk8n, check the todos

Comment: What does that show? It's totally different; there's no `map` at all and you're using `HttpClient`.

Comment: Thats what I meant, I missed the fact this was using `Http` and not `HttpClient`. The stackblitz shows that if you add a type to the `http.get`. TypeScript infers the type in you component call.

Comment: anyway @AmiraAbdouli recreate the issue on stackblitz if you can

Comment: There's enough information in the question to determine the problem already, please read my comment above.